# What fuels high-reputation users to ask low-quality posts?

Tags: discussion

I just viewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261982/logging-in-performance-critical-python-code) which came from a user with 5,000 reputation, and plenty badges (clearly an established user). This post, while the OP probably had good intentions, was low-quality and didn't show evident research.

What fuels some established users to make posts like this? They should obviously know the rules, and yet they still think it's OK to post this? Or am I just being to hard on them?

[image]

Comment: 5858 rep acquired over 7 years != an established, high-rep user in my book

Comment: Reputation score is not such a great unit to measure how a user understand the site's rules, I'm afraid.

Comment: What fuels them? A lack of care for the system and a desire to get an answer I guess? Just like new users who do it.

Comment: "hi-rep" tends to be conflated with "knowledgeable".  That however doesn't usually apply when a user asked hundreds of questions but posted only a few answers.  Add the general trends of doing no research, because it wasn't needed before, and to post as little info as possible to prevent a question from getting closed as a dup and you'll easily end up with something like that.  [python] users do seem to put up with less lately, about time.

Comment: Your comment to him was a little rude, I think. It would help him better if you give him a constructive remark.

Comment: Your use of "fuels" implies you think these users _intentionally_ ask bad questions. Some people (myself included) are just better at answering than asking. I personally know the rules, but in the rare case that I have a question that hasn't already been asked, it takes a lot of effort for me to ask it properly.

Comment: Those user trend to have some by pass on quality. With poor question getting upvote and answered.

Comment: Did I miss something?  What makes this question "low quality"?

Comment: @Makoto Lack of research, no attempt to find an answer experimentally, too broad, not a clear question.  What makes you think it's a quality question?

Comment: @Servy:  I don't think it's *high* quality.  I just don't see it being all that *poor*, either.

Answer (score 14):

High reputation doesn't necessarily reflect someone's familiarity with the system. Some users could've gained points from asking some questions that went popular for some reason.

If you really want to "measure" someone's knowledge, you can go through his profile and view his posts.

Side note: I find your comment

> Wow, sad to see a question like this from an established account...

a bit inappropriate. If you think the questions should be improved, you should suggest an edit, or point to the problematic parts of the question. Users with the privileges can and will close the question if they find it poor. But such comments are not really constructive, not to the community and especially not for OP.

Comment: An addition to the side note, there are ways to advise a person without coming across as being condescending, your approach is not one of them. You could've cut out the '*Wow*' and the ellipsis and rephrased it to focus on what is wrong with the question (too broad? opinion based?).

Comment: @Script47 did you mean to leave that comment on the Q?

Comment: @JonClements it was more of addition on to Maroun's answer where he makes mentions of the OP's comment. However I didn't wish to add it on as Maroun might not agree with what I'm saying so I left it as a comment instead in the instance that Maroun wanted to add it on. If you feel it would be better suited on the question chain, then let me know.

Comment: @Script47 it's fine thanks - appears the point's already been made.